# latex equation not displaying correct format

Tags: symbols, equations

my equation not displaying in expected format. can any one help me to correct this equation to display exactly the same as source..
i used this code

```
\alpha=a_{1}+\frac{1}{a_{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_{n}+\frac{1}{\alpha_{n+1}}}}.
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\cfrac` (continued fraction) instead of the normal `\frac`

Comment: @SeanAllred an answer? :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `\cfrac` (which stands for *continued fraction*) instead of the normal `\frac`.  Unlike `\frac`, `\cfrac` does not scale its arguments (at least not *nearly* as much) and instead focuses on enlarging the fraction box as a whole.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,b6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath} % Contains the definition of \cfrac

\begin{document}
\section*{Using \texttt{frac}}
$\alpha=a_{1}+\frac{1}{a_{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_{n}+\frac{1}{\alpha_{n+1}}}}$

In \verb|equation|:
\begin{equation*}
  \alpha=a_{1}+\frac{1}{a_{2}+\dots+\cfrac{1}{a_{n}+\frac{1}{\alpha_{n+1}}}}
\end{equation*}

\section*{With \texttt{cfrac}}
$\alpha=a_{1}+\cfrac{1}{a_{2}+\cdots+\cfrac{1}{a_{n}+\cfrac{1}{\alpha_{n+1}}}}$

In \verb|equation|:
\begin{equation*}
  \alpha=a_{1}+\cfrac{1}{a_{2}+\cdots+\cfrac{1}{a_{n}+\cfrac{1}{\alpha_{n+1}}}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]